# Using placement new

Tags: c++

The code below works for me. How could this work? Wouldn't this segfault?

```
char * buffer = new char[100];
float * in_buf = new(buffer) float[100];
```

Also i got a class like this:

```
class Item
{
public:
   Item(int num)
   {
     u = new float[num];
     v = new float[num];
   }
   float * u;
   float * v;
   //And many other variables
}
```

I want to create a block of memory and allocate v and u within them. Is this approach safe?

```
class Item
{
public:
   Item(int num)
   {
     buffer = new char[(sizeof(char)+2*sizeof(float))*num];
     u = new (buffer) float[num];
     v = new (buffer+sizeof(float)*num) float[num];
   }
   char * buffer;
   float * u;
   float * v;
   //And many other variables
}
```

Comment: `(sizeof(char)+2*sizeof(float))*num` why not `sizeof(*v) + sizeof(*u)`?

Comment: `*v` and `*u` are `float`, so `sizeof(*v) + sizeof(*u)` would be `sizeof(float) + sizeof(float) = 8.` I don't know why `sizeof(char)` is being used at all.  I would use `(sizeof(float)*num)*2` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I like getting the sizeof of the actual variable better. If Vivek some day decides to make `v` a double, he has to track down all possible usages of float. That will make the maintaining a horror.

Comment: I was commenting more on the use of `sizeof() + sizeof()`, which would be too small of a value for this situation. A more appropriate calculation, while allowing either variable type to be changed, would be `(sizeof(*v) * num) + (sizeof(*u) * num)`, or `(sizeof(*v) + sizeof(*u)) * num` (maybe that latter one is what you were thinking of earlier?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The code below works for me. How could this work? Wouldn't this segfault?

```
char* buffer = new char[100];
float* in_buf = new(buffer) float[100];
```

What does "works" mean?  As the `new`s here aren't required to initialise/construct the data types in question, they don't (necessarily) trigger reads or writes from the memory you're implicity planning to use for them.  So, one reason you may not see a segfault is that the code's *effectively* only doing this:

```
char* buffer = new char[100];
float* in_buf = reinterpret_cast<float*>(buffer);
```

If you move on to read or write ala `in_buf[99] = 2;`, you're more likely to get a segfault but far from guaranteed - it could be that the memory at that address is in the applicaton's virtual address space.  For example, say the request for 100 characters was satisfied by a request for one page of memory and the OS page size was >= 4096 bytes - 1000 4-byte floats would coincidentally fit, or because an earlier `new` and `delete` had already mapped the memory.  Even if it didn't actually segfault immediately, it's likely to crash or corrupt the heap or other heap-hosted data one day.  More generally, there are plenty of unsafe things you can do in C++ that won't actually bite immediately....

> is this safe?

```
buffer = new char[(sizeof(char)+2*sizeof(float))*num];
u = new (buffer) float[num];
v = new (buffer+sizeof(float)*num) float[num];
```

Yes (assuming sane values of num), but it's pointlessly complicated (and the extra character's pointless and actively confusing).  You could simply do:

```
u = new float[2 * num];
v = &u[num];
```

Answer (score 3):

1. The second statement is potential UB (you are using `buffer` as back-storage for 100 `float`, and they surely more memory than 100 `char`). Still, I'm not entirely sure about the UB, because the default action `new` does for scalar types is to leave them uninitialized, so no memory is actually touched on that statement.
2. Sure, you could do it, but it's a useless overcomplication, just use a plain `new`. Keep in mind that placement `new` is there only for few corner cases, in general it shouldn't be used.

Comment: If the goal is a single allocation for both pointers, there is a better way to achieve it. Also, why not vectors?

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your first question can be illustrated with a change so minor, you can't see it unless you compare the code side-by-side:

```
char * buffer = new char[100];
float * in_buf = new(buffer) float[100]();
```

This gives me a run-time heap corruption error in MSVS.

Comment: For OP: this surely segfaults because the empty `()` at the end invoke zero-initialization for arithmetic types, which means that the compiler will fill with zero the 100 floats, exposing immediately that there's not enough backing storage for the float array.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers mentioned, the line `float * in_buf = new(buffer) float[100];` is putting most of the array past the bounds of `buffer`. It's not segfaulting because the memory hasn't yet been touched.

If u and v don't have meaningful constructors (i.e. they're zero-initialized), then placement new doesn't make sense and won't be as clear as something like this:

```
class Item
{
public:
    Item(int num)
    {
        size_t buffer_size = sizeof(*buffer);
        size_t u_size = sizeof(*u) * num;
        size_t v_size = sizeof(*v) * num;
        buffer = new char[buffer_size + u_size + v_size];
        u = reinterpret_cast<float* >(buffer + buffer_size);
        v = reinterpret_cast<float* >(buffer + buffer_size + u_size);
    }
    char * buffer;
    float * u;
    float * v;
    //And many other variables
};
```

Do you need to have a runtime `num` parameter? If you can get away with it, I'd suggest making Item templated like this:

```
template <int NUM>
class Item
{
public:
    Item() {}
    char buffer[NUM];
    float u[NUM];
    float v[NUM];
    //And many other variables
};
```